# Rolling up data to higher organization level

Tags: python, pandas, database

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm hoping someone can help me with organizational type of data. I have a company org table (org_table) that looks something like this, note that there can be nulls somewhere in the org level, but the highest and the lowest levels are never null

| Super Division | Division | Super Department | Department | Sub Department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 342 | 767 | 546 | 965 |
| 345 | 453 | 234 | na | 759 |

And I also have a table containing "reports" (report_table) that are associated to an org, which can be at any level. so it looks something like this

| Report Name | Org Level | Org ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Division | 342 |
| DEF | Super Department | 234 |
| GHI | Super Division | 123 |

I want to get a result set which contains the same list of reports but now rolled up to the highest level. so something like this. How would I accomplish this?

| Report Name | Org Level | Org ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Division | 342 |
| ABC | Super Division | 123 |
| DEF | Super Department | 234 |
| DEF | Division | 453 |
| DEF | Super Division | 345 |
| GHI | Super Division | 123 |

I've tried writing a function that retrieves the rollups but then the result set is giving me all the lower levels too.

```
`    def get_org_rollup(row):
        org_level = row['Org Level']
        org_rollups = []
        for i, level in enumerate(org_table.columns):
            if level == org_level:
                org_rollups.append(row['Org ID'])
            elif not pd.isnull(org_table.iloc[row.name, i]):
                org_rollups.append(org_table.iloc[row.name, i])
            else:
                break
        return pd.Series(org_rollups, index=org_table.columns[:len(org_rollups)])`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty neat one-liner for you you trying to do without creating a function.

```
(pd.concat([df.where((df == x).iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(1).astype(bool)).melt().dropna() 
           for x in dfr['Org ID']], keys=dfr['Report Name'])
   .reset_index()
   .drop('level_1', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  Report Name          variable  value
0         ABC    Super Division  123.0
1         ABC          Division  342.0
2         DEF    Super Division  345.0
3         DEF          Division  453.0
4         DEF  Super Department  234.0
5         GHI    Super Division  123.0
```

Details:

Using reversing element, `::-1`, I going to keep all values left of True on each row with `cumsum`.  Then, use this boolean matrix to return only those True values using `where`.  Next we, use `melt` to convert from wide to long, then `pd.concat` the above results by row using list comprehension and last `reset_index` and `drop` the level_1 column.